# MySQL Add Friend | Remove Friend - Follow | Unfollow system efficiency

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a table named [ friends ], and this for rows and such.

+-----------------------------------friend_id | friend_one | friend_two | role--------------------------------------------+
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

It's a follow and unfollow system, but it's not too great.

For the Add and remove friend, I want to know how I can make this more efficient, so that I can read from the database much easier, and just more reliable.

```
// Add Friend
public function Add_Friend($uid,$fid){
    $fid            = mysql_real_escape_string($fid);
    $q          = mysql_query("SELECT friend_id FROM friends WHERE friend_one='$uid' AND friend_two='$fid' AND role='fri'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($q) ==0 ){
        $query      = mysql_query("INSERT INTO friends(friend_one,friend_two,role) VALUES ('$uid','$fid','fri')") or die(mysql_error());    
        $query      = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET friend_count=friend_count+1 WHERE uid='$uid'") or die(mysql_error());   
        return true;
    }
}

// Remove Friend
public function Remove_Friend($uid,$fid){
    $fid            = mysql_real_escape_string($fid);
    $q          = mysql_query("SELECT friend_id FROM friends WHERE friend_one='$uid' AND friend_two='$fid' AND role='fri'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($q) == 1){
        $query      = mysql_query("DELETE FROM friends WHERE friend_one='$uid' AND friend_two='$fid'") or die(mysql_error());
        $query      = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET friend_count=friend_count-1 WHERE uid='$uid'") or die(mysql_error());   
        return true;
    }

}
```

Everything is working fine, I just want to know how I could go by making it easier. Because right now I'm trying to read how many friends I'm currently following but it's nearly impossible for me to do it with my current knowledge of SQL.

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Comment: Thank you @charles, I'm currently reading on PDO and understanding more about it as I'm learling still. Yet, I'm still looking for an answer on the above question!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to don't run this query

```
$fid            = mysql_real_escape_string($fid);
$q          = mysql_query("SELECT friend_id FROM friends WHERE friend_one='$uid' AND friend_two='$fid' AND role='fri'");
```

bcoz obvoiusly in case of **add_friend**, the two ids are **not connected to each other** then only you will call this function, so no need to use the query.

And in case of **remove friend**, the two ids are **connected to each other** then only you will call this function.

So, I suggest to remove the two lines. And also, your approach is nice, so move ahead with this.

Comment: I'm sorry, how are the two id's not connected in add_friend but in remove_friend they aren't, do you have a better suggestion on how I may go on this!?

Comment: Obviously the two ids are not connected to each other or i will say that they are not friend to each other then only you will make them friends else you will show them as friend.